# Implementing a stream with signalr

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, signalr

I have a simple Razor Page that I want to stream log data to use SingalR.

The difficulty I have found is gaining access to the Hub which would send data. I've seen some code examples using HostContext, but I'm not sure if some of it is deprecated or if because I am somehow using the AspNetcore and AspNet versions of SingalR, I am unable to use this method.

Is there an example or a design pattern for implementing a stream of one way data with SignalR? the key is having other parts of the server process be able to send the log messages as well.

Is this the wrong technology for this? Are there any examples?

Answer (score 0):

Wrong technology - No but some research would show you this is not being approached properly.

You stated "using the AspNetcore and AspNet versions of SingalR, I am unable to use this method." This is simply because ASP.NET Core SignalR isn't compatible with clients or servers for ASP.NET SignalR. [(source)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/version-differences?view=aspnetcore-5.0) You need to pick which one you need but this will be obvious as shown below.

Are there any examples? - ASP.NET Core SignalR now supports streaming data from the hub to the client. [(source)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/version-differences?view=aspnetcore-5.0#streaming) SignalR (.NET 4.x) does not support streaming, although you can send data to the client at high rate, about 25 messages per second, it's not actual streaming. [Streaming Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/streaming?view=aspnetcore-5.0)